# Error attempting to account for spatial correlation in R

Tags: r, geospatial

I am trying to account for spatial correlation in a very small dataset, but am receiving the following error message:

```
Error in corFactor.corSpatial(object) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)
In addition: Warning message:
In min(unlist(attr(object, "covariate"))) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

I understand that the dataset is likely too small, but still want to know what generates this error. I would appreciate any help understanding this.

Here is the dataset and code that generates the error:

```
df = structure(list(y = c(58.8642857142857, 43.3142857142857, 
56.55, 43.8642857142857, 43.613025210084, 41.2142857142857, 44.05, 
33.0214285714286, 31.8642857142857, 28.7, 22.4, 34.0094537815126, 
27.5357142857143), east = c(2119, 2134, 2145, 2084, 583, 574, 537, 
37, 32, 0, 2419, 2427, 2451), north = c(29, 65, 0, 23, 578, 537, 
537, 1005, 979, 966, 157, 193, 138), x = c(92.5321292115318, 
48.5305364361411, 52.4519419380149, 68.594674556213, 91.1010260457774, 
94.669993195736, 59.5802764033442, 48.3502375144434, 39.9654539566015, 
46.5365298967118, 39.5309734513274, 58.7253229344382, 40.9344115004492
), dummy = 1:13), row.names = c(12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L), class = "data.frame")

model <- lme(fixed = y ~ x, data = df, random = ~ 1 | dummy, method = "ML") 
summary(model)

sp_model <- update(model, correlation = corGaus(1, form = ~ east + north), method = "ML")
summary(sp_model)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out what went wrong? Currently running into the same problem.

Comment: I did not, but haven't revisited for quite some time.